# Running a selenium based exe to scrape data

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, geckodriver

## What is working

I have created a Python file that opens a Firefox browser using Selenium and scrapes data to a excel file. I have also converted this file to exe. No errors were created during exe. This was done by Pyinstaller.

## What is not working.

When I run the new created exe on official laptop it doesn't open a browser or give any output. Just a command window opens and closes immediately.

## What is my intention.

My intention is to share this script with colleagues so that the data needed can be easily scraped to excel file on any PC and would be efficient process rather than looking up the same on website. I would not want to them to have any admin access to change anything on their PC. Also, I do not want them to have multiple browsers opening up on their PC.

## Question

Do I need to install and provide geckodriver path on every PC? Perhaps this is the reason Firefox is not opening despite being available?

## Code Below

```
     from selenium import webdriver
     from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
     from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
     import pandas as pd
     

     productName = []
     number = []
     divList = []

     driver = webdriver.Firefox()
     driver.get("website")

     radioBtn = driver.find_element_by_id("ContentPlaceHolder1_company")
     radioBtn.click()

            
     element = driver.find_element_by_id("ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBoxInput1")
     element.send_keys("CompanyName")

     
    Search = driver.find_element_by_id("ContentPlaceHolder1_view1Continue")
    Search.click()

   driver.implicitly_wait(10)

   driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_92564").click()

    driver.implicitly_wait(2)

    divList = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('nopgbrk')

    for div in divList:
    number.append(div.find_element_by_xpath('a').text)
    productName.append(div.find_element_by_xpath('span').text)

    df = pd.DataFrame({'Product':productName, 'Registration': number})

    df.to_excel("C:\Python\Scrapeddata\Scrape.xls")
```

Comment: Can you share the code? The reasons could be numerous. Wouldn't you get an error message if driver not on either explicit path or environmental path?

Comment: @QHarr - Just did.

Comment: I would have thought, irrespective of cause, you will need all users to have the folder containing the driver on the environmental path. The alternative is that they all need to use the same path and you pass that path as an argument.

Comment: Is there an option on bypassing Geckodriver alttogether?

Comment: Do all users have a default IE install in same place? Though IE brings it own problems.

Comment: First I would check 4 things: 1 - does script run properly without exe on the same "official laptop"; 2 - add output statements in various places in script to see if the script is even a problem. And run exe from cmd window to see if it creates any output; if none of your output is there, then exe fails before even invoking script; depending on outcome: either debug generation of exe (maybe it's not runnable), or if you see some output, it will tell you which part of script is failing. And 4 - try to "run as administrator"

Answer (score 0):

I anticipate, the reason for this would be the incompatibility of chromedriver version and the chrome version of your official laptop.

In the development phase, the system on which it was being developed had chrome, whose version was compatible with selenium chromedriver version. So it ran and processed output successfully. But your official laptop did not have the same version that of your system's chrome, so it is not compatible.

Please check chrome version by going to settings -> About Chrome.

Download chromedriver for the same version which you checked above from here and then create exe if it supports:

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Or if you know the version of your chromedriver the easiest would be to uninstall  chrome on your official laptop and install chrome of the same version that of chromedriver.